# How can I host my own previously made Android Projects/Libraries(that include resources) locally?

Tags: android, android-studio, maven, repository

I am hoping this question has an answer, I want to host some of my previously made Android Projects/Libraries that include resources (drawables, styles, colors, etc..) on my local network because I'd like the ability to add projects/libraries I've made, into other projects/libraries I've made.

The things I've tried:

- Exporting then importing JAR files (Doesn't support resources)
- Exporting then importing AAR files (Cannot add ARR files into other AAR files)

Also, I was beginning to looking hosting a local maven repository but am not sure if that is overkill or the correct thing to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out hosting a local maven repository was the answer I wanted, as it allows me to put projects I've made (with or without resources) into other projects I've made.

What helped me was looking into the 'maven-publish' plugin for android studio projects and specifically the 'publishToMavenLocal' task that this plugin enables.